# Why study the moment problem in one dimensional case( Hamburger moment problem)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, moments

I have been reading about moment problem and I have been curious about the following question.

What is the motivation for studying the Hamburger moment problem(one dimensional moment problem?

I have been asking myself out of curiosity, what is gained by people who considered this case? or let me say how can  I explain my reasons to someone who has little knowledge about the subject the reasons for for studying hamburger moment problem.

I will be more than happy if useful literatures can be suggested or provided with some explanations.

Thanks for your useful suggestions and explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has many applications, especially in probability: e.g. you want to know if there is a probability distribution satisfying some condition on its moments.
Or you know the moments of a random variable match those of a certain distribution, and you want to know if that implies this is the distribution of the random variable.

I'm not claiming this as a major motivation, but [one of my papers](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103904299) happens to contain an application of the Hamburger moment problem to mathematical physics: 
a characterization of reflection positivity for pair interactions in one-dimensional lattice systems (see Prop. 3.2).